# Position figcaption vertically centered and next to image?

Tags: image, figure, caption

I have an image and a caption within a `figure` tag. I was wondering how I can get the `figcaption` positioned next to the `img` and vertically centered, like the image attached.

[image]

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/45MHk/568/) I set up.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, just replace the css with following:

```
html { font-family: 'Helvetica-Neue', Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.4; letter-spacing: 1px; color:white; }
figure { float:left; padding:20px; display:block; background:#ffa2df; position:relative; }
.width { width:50%; }
.height { height:15em; }
img { width:auto; height:100%; float:left;}
figcaption { background:#5800ff; height:100%; display:flex; justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
text-align: center; 
float:left; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not quite there! The width of the image needs to be set to "auto". Anyway this can still work?

Comment: Yes, I just modified my answer.